# Regex producing one incorrect result

Tags: java, regex, ant

I am stumped on a particular regex (I am tantalizingly close, but not able to get over this last hurdle yet.

I need to extract a branch type and an "initiative" from series of git branches that have slight variations in their names. The branch type goes into group 1 and the initiative goes into group 2. Versions begin with either "v" or nothing at all.

Desired Inputs/Outputs are:

```
branchname          | group 1 | group 2
release/v1.2.3      | release | ""      
release/1.2.3       | release | ""
release/foo-v1.2.3  | release | foo
release/foo-1.2.3   | release | foo
```

My current regex is: `(release)\/(\w*)-?(?=v?\d+\.\d+\.\d*)`

This produces the following Inputs/Outputs:

```
branchname          | group 1 | group 2
release/v1.2.3      | release | "v"      <--- Problem!
release/1.2.3       | release | ""
release/foo-v1.2.3  | release | foo
release/foo-1.2.3   | release | foo
```

My issue is with the case where I have only `v1.2.3`. I don't want to go back through and change the branch names if I can help it (we have a ton of them with the name `release/vX.Y.Z` due to a decision made a long time ago).

I'm using Ant on a Linux system for this regex, so I need to follow Java rules, I believe.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *were* super close! Try appending a `?` to your second match group, like so:

`(release)\/(\w*?)-?(?=v?\d+\.\d+\.\d*)`

[See this working in regexr](http://regexr.com/3gmht).

Comment: I knew it was going to be something simple like this! One day, I will win against regexes.  

Since you were first and your answer is correct, I will give the answer to you, unless @revo can argue his as a superior solution. 

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You'd better apply optional property to whole `\w+-` pattern:

```
(release)\/(?:(\w+)-)?v?\d+(?:\.\d+)*
```

It seems you don't need lookahead as well.